# iyzipay-laravel - Invalid signature when trying to make Single Charge

Tags: php, laravel

**THE SITUATION**

I am using [iyzipay-laravel](https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-laravel) to handle payments in my application.

Regarding plans subscriptions everything works fine. 
But I also need to make single charges to the user when he purchase specific products.
And this part doesn't work.

**DOCS**

These are the only docs available regarding Single Charge using iyzipay-laravel:
https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-laravel/wiki/Usage#single-charges

**TABLES**

This is the producs table.

[image: product table]

The user table has a proper `iyzipay_key` field:

[image]

**THE CODE**

I store products in an Eloquent way:

```
$product = new Product;
$product->name = $package->name;
$product->category = 'extra-package';
$product->type = BasketItemType::VIRTUAL;
$product->price = $package->total_cost;
$product->save();
```

Then I make a test call to the `pay` method, where I pass the products Collection, the currency, the number of installments and the subscription:

```
$products = Product::where('id', 1)->get();
$subscription = Subscription::where('billable_id', $user->id)->first();

$user->pay($products, 'TRY', 1, $subscription);
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

This is what I get back from the API call:

```
message: "589004: Invalid signature"
exception: "Iyzico\IyzipayLaravel\Exceptions\Transaction\TransactionSaveException"
file: "my_project/vendor/iyzico/iyzipay-laravel/src/IyzipayLaravel.php"
line: 121
```

(589004 are the first 6 numbers of the test credit card used. The credit cards testing numbers are taken from the list in this page: https://dev.iyzipay.com/en/api/auth).

I have been trying to tweak around the library source code, but to no avail.

**THIRD PARTY SOURCE CODE**

This is the `pay()` method, of the **Payable trait**.

```
/**
 * Single payment for the payable
 *
 * @param Collection $products
 * @param string $currency
 * @param int $installment
 * @param bool $subscription
 * @return Transaction
 */
public function pay(Collection $products, $currency = 'TRY', $installment = 1, $subscription = false): Transaction
{
    return IyzipayLaravel::singlePayment($this, $products, $currency, $installment, $subscription);
}
```

This is the `singlePayment()` method, of the **IyzipayLaravel class** :

```
/**
 * @param PayableContract $payable
 * @param Collection $products
 * @param $currency
 * @param $installment
 * @param bool $subscription
 *
 * @return Transaction $transactionModel
 * @throws TransactionSaveException
 */
public function singlePayment(Payable $payable, Collection $products, $currency, $installment, $subscription = false): Transaction
{
    $this->validateBillable($payable);
    $this->validateHasCreditCard($payable);

    $messages = []; // @todo imporove here
    foreach ($payable->creditCards as $creditCard) {
        try {
            $transaction = $this->createTransactionOnIyzipay(
                $payable,
                $creditCard,
                compact('products', 'currency', 'installment'),
                $subscription
            );

            return $this->storeTransactionModel($transaction, $payable, $products, $creditCard);
        } catch (TransactionSaveException $e) {
            $messages[] = $creditCard->number . ': ' . $e->getMessage();
            continue;
        }
    }

    throw new TransactionSaveException(implode(', ', $messages));
}
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I make single charge using iyzipay-laravel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

iyzipay-laravel has been deprecated for subscription and single payment.

For subscription,

Documentation: https://dev.iyzipay.com/en/subscription

Client: https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-php

Single Payment,

Documentation: https://dev.iyzipay.com/en/api/auth

Client: https://github.com/iyzico/iyzipay-php

If you can forward your e-mail address to integration@iyzico.com, we will be happy to help.

Comment: Okay thanks for replying. And thanks for the offer of help. I will write in case if I will have some issues! However on the official iyzipay-laravel github repo there is no mention that is deprecated. There is written: Now officially maintained by iyzico. It would have been much better if it was clear that it was deprecated. The pity is that I will have to throw away a lot of code already written.